# Trouble with Go

Tags: windows, go, installation, environment-variables

I decided to download go last night and see what it was all about.  Trouble is, I can't get the damn thing to function.  I downloaded the program, created a workspace, tried using the `go install` command, and nothing.  I have my workspace located at `C:\go\src\gocode` in which is my `hello.go` file.  I tried manually setting the GOPATH variable to this location via `setx GOPATH C:\go\src\gocode`, but no luck.  Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the error? Usually, the go binary prints some helpful bits of information when something goes wrong.

Comment: Where exactly is hello.go? Your hello.go ought to be in a subdirectory of %GOPATH%\src.

Answer (score 4):

> The Go project provides two installation options for Windows users
>   (besides installing from source): a zip archive that requires you to
>   set some environment variables and an MSI installer that configures
>   your installation automatically.
>
> MSI installer
>
> Open the MSI file(https://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/Downloads?tm=2)
>   and follow the prompts to install the Go tools. By default, the
>   installer puts the Go distribution in c:\Go.
>
> The installer should put the c:\Go\bin directory in your PATH
>   environment variable. You may need to restart any open command prompts
>   for the change to take effect.
>
> Zip archive
>
> Download the zip(https://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/Downloads?tm=2)
>   file and extract it into the directory of your choice (we suggest
>   c:\Go).
>
> If you chose a directory other than c:\Go, you must set the GOROOT
>   environment variable to your chosen path.
>
> Add the bin subdirectory of your Go root (for example, c:\Go\bin) to
>   your PATH environment variable.
>
> Setting environment variables under Windows
>
> Under Windows, you may set environment variables through the
>   "Environment Variables" button on the "Advanced" tab of the "System"
>   control panel. Some versions of Windows provide this control panel
>   through the "Advanced System Settings" option inside the "System"
>   control panel.

This is from : *http://golang.org/doc/install*

Answer (score 3):

For a quick way to install golang on windows, try the [MSI installer](http://golang.org/doc/install#windows_msi). The installer will only add the `C:\Go\bin` directory to your `PATH`, you need to setup the `GOPATH` manually in your environement settings.

From the golang site:

> Under Windows, you may set environment variables through the "Environment Variables" button on the "Advanced" tab of the "System" control panel. Some versions of Windows provide this control panel through the "Advanced System Settings" option inside the "System" control panel.

Then just add a variable name `GOPATH` with the right location. You should choose a location different from `GOROOT` to ensure you don't mix standard package with yours.

Comment: I did use the MSI installer, that's what's so frustrating!  When I was initially having trouble, I looked in my variables and found that it hadn't put a GOPATH variable.  Hence the manually reassigning it.

Comment: Updated my answer with how to setup the `GOPATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your preferences and requirements, try this:

In windows command console, try enter the following line,
including the quote marks shown, and then hit ENTER key:

```
setx PATH "c\go\bin;C:\go\src\gocode"
```